# How to publish messages with specific data types for arguments?

Tags: ros-hydro, roscpp, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've adapted some C++ control code for a smart motor I have attached to a laser scanner (it rotates the laser scanner back and forth) into a node to do the same thing upon receiving a custom message.  The message includes start/end angle, speed, and duration, which are the inputs the original control code uses:

```
  float32 start
  float32 end
  float32 speed
  float32 duration
```

The node compiles and runs (the code as is can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wypDERQL).  Now I am trying to complete a simple back and forth sweep for 3 seconds, by publishing a custom Sweep message to the /sweep topic from the command line.  I run the command:

```
  rostopic pub -1 /sweep toro/Sweep -- -3.14159/2 3.14159/2 3.14159/2 3
```

but get the following response (repeated many times):

```
 [WARN] [WallTime: 1408045951.800915] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not  a float' when writing 'start: -3.14159/2
 end: 3.14159/2
 speed: 3.14159/2
 duration: 3'
```

Is there any kind of way I can specify the data type of the arguments while publishing the message?  I guess they might be doubles by default, but ros custom messages don't support doubles (or at least I couldn't get them to work), so I don't think I can fix the problem on that end.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190284/how-to-publish-messages-with-specific-data-types-for-arguments?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The trouble here is that rostopic pub is not a calculator - it's expecting numbers, and instead you're giving it an equation (effectively a string).

Instead, try:

```
  rostopic pub -1 /sweep toro/Sweep -- -1.57 1.57 1.57 3
```

P.S. - The ROS message type for doubles is float64 (since most doubles are 64-bit floating-precision numbers)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-14**:
Great, that completely solved the problem!  Thanks for such a helpful answer, and the information on the doubles.